# In vector space $V,$ if $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1, \dots , v_n\}=V$ and $u\in V,$ prove that $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1, \dots , v_n, u\} = V.$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let $v_1, \dots , v_n$ be vectors which span a vector space $V,$ and let $u$ be a vector in $V.$ Prove
that $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1, \dots, v_n, u\} = V .$

So far I have:

> Let v1, ..., vn be vectors which span a vector space V and let u be a vector in V. I wish to prove that span{u, v1, ..., vn} = V. We know that span{v1,...,vn}=V and thus for some arbitrary vector z in V, then k1v1+...+knvn=z, where k1,...,kn are scalars. Let span{v1,...,vn,u} be the set of all linear combinations of the form k1v1+...+knvn+cu, where k1,...,kn,c are scalars. Therefore k1v1+...+knvn+cu=z+cu.

I'm stuck here. I know I need to show that z=k1v1+...+knvn+cu, but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: Isn't it obvious $\text{span} \{v_1, \cdots, v_n, u\} \subset \text{\span}\{v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$?

Comment: $u$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$. Thus, $\text{span}(\{v_1, \ldots, v_n, u\}) = \text{span}(\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}) = V$ (because $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\} \cup \{u\}$ is linearly dependent, $\text{span}$ "disregards" the $u$).

Comment: Choose $c=0$ and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking too complicated. The span of a set is either defined as the set of all finite linear combinations from the set or equivalently as the smallest subspace of $V$ containing the set.

Anyway, it is trivial to see that the span has some monotonous property: If $A\subseteq B$ any finite linear combination of elements of $A$ is also one of elements of $B$ (or any subspace that contains $B$ also contains $A$). Thus $\mathrm{span} A\subseteq\mathrm{span} B$.

Thus you get
$$ V = \mathrm{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\} \subseteq \mathrm{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,u\}\subseteq V$$
This implies that actually
$$ V = \mathrm{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\} = \mathrm{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,u\}= V$$